# Rename files named 1, 2, 3,..., 10, 11, ... in folder to 001, 002, 003,..., 010, 011,... in that order

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-14.04

I have a set of files in a folder and they are named as 1, 2 , 3, ..., 10, 11,... and I am running a MATLAB code on these files and it is taking the files as 1, 10, 11, 12,...(wrong order) which I don't want.
I want to get the files in the sequence 1, 2, 3, ... only.
So, is there a way to do this in MATLAB (I am using dir() command to get all the files of the folder)?

My MATLAB code goes as follows:

```
file_names= dir('DirContainingFiles1,2,3,...');
for imgj=1: length(file_names)
    file= file_names(imgj).name;
    ......
    ......
end
```

So, this file variable above is supposed to get all the files in each loop in a sequence 1, 2, 3,...
But it is getting in 1, 10, 11,... sequence (text based scheme).
Please help in getting it in numbered sequence.

Comment: Sort them, of course.

Comment: Actually, this (1, 10, 11. ... ) is the correct sorted order in text based scheme. Please clarify.

Comment: Then, sort them by numerical value. Or are you asking how to sort a list of strings by numerical value in Matlab? I'm pretty sure you already know how.

Comment: Yes okay. Thanks a lot for clarifying! :)

Comment: You may remove the `shell` tag from this.

Comment: Thanks, duly noted.

Comment: @user202729 , I have a 410X1 struct variable which needs the sorting but the answers I am finding are for sorting a cell array... How to convert?

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged this with `shell`, I assume you are happy to correct the issue in the shell. So, you could use `rename` (also known as `Perl rename` and `prename`) in the shell to zero pad all numbers out to say, 5 places:

```
rename --dry-run 's/\d+/sprintf("%05d",$&)/e' *
```

So, if I start with this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 0
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 1
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 11
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 2
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 Freddy 73 Frog
```

I end up with this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 00000
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 00001
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 00002
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 00011
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    0 16 Jan 12:23 Freddy 00073 Frog
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MATLAB solution:

```
cd DirContainingFiles1,2,3,...
names = strsplit(ls);
[~,idx]=sort(str2double(names));
for name = names(idx)
    disp(name{1})
    ....
end
```

You don't need to rename files. Get list of the files using [ls](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html). Convert them to numeric format and get index of the sorted elements.

If you want to use `dir`:

```
file_names= dir('DirContainingFiles1,2,3,...'); 
names = {file_names(3:end).name};
[~,idx]=sort(str2double(names));
for name = names(idx)
    disp(name{1})
    ....
end
```

Comment: Here, I have a 410X1 struct variable as "name" which needs to be sorted. How to do it?

Comment: Thanks @rahnema1!

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
[natsortfiles][1](file_names);
```

before entering the loop, it sorts by numerical value
while

```
sort(file_names);
```

sorts by text based value.

Comment: `natsortfiles` is not builtin function.  If you are using something out of the file exchange you should add a link to it.

Comment: Sure. https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10959-sort-nat--natural-order-sort